# Default parameters to actions with Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Is there a way to have a default parameter passed to a action in the case where the regex didnt match anything using django?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',(r'^test/(?P<name>.*)?$','myview.displayName'))

#myview.py
def displayName(request,name):
      # write name to response or something
```

I have tried setting the third parameter in the urlpatterns to a dictionary containing ' and giving the name parameter a default value on the method, none of which worked. the name parameter always seems to be None. I really dont want to code a check for None if i could set a default value.

Clarification: here is an example of what i was changing it to.

```
def displayName(request,name='Steve'):
      return HttpResponse(name)
#i also tried

urlpatterns = patterns('',
      (r'^test/(?P<name>.*)?$',
        'myview.displayName',
        dict(name='Test')
      )
)
```

when i point my browser at the view it displays the text
'None'

Any ideas?

Comment: A complete aside, the final '?' is unnecessary as '*' will match zero or more characters, thus, '^test/.*$' matches both 'test/' and 'test/name' just fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when the pattern is matched against 'test/' the groupdict captured by the regex contains the mapping 'name' => None:

```
>>> url.match("test/").groupdict()
{'name': None}
```

This means that when the view is invoked, using something I expect that is similar to below:

```
view(request, *groups, **groupdict)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
view(request, name = None)
```

for 'test/', meaning that name is assigned None rather than not assigned.

This leaves you with two options. You can:

1. Explicitly check for None in the view code which is kind of hackish.
2. Rewrite the url dispatch rule to make the name capture non-optional and introduce a second rule to capture when no name is provided.

For example:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^test/(?P<name>.+)$','myview.displayName'), # note the '+' instead of the '*'
    (r'^test/$','myview.displayName'),
)
```

When taking the second approach, you can simply call the method without the capture pattern, and let python handle the default parameter or you can call a different view which delegates.

Answer (score 0):

I *thought* you could `def displayName(request, name=defaultObj)`; that's what I've done in the past, at least. What were you setting the default value to?

Comment: Were you doing that in a Django view action where the pattern for that URL contains an optional named capture for that parameter? Because that's not working for me. Thanks

Comment: I did it in a pattern with a parameter (not a named one).